# The best way for finding the closest line segment to a point

Tags: algorithm, line, distance, point

As can be seen in figure below, I have some lines (finite length) between any two joints (red points), such  as the line between joints J1 and J2. I have also some points such as P1 and P2.

I have the coordinates of points and joints. So, it is possible to calculate the line equations (y=mx+b). So, it is possible to calculate the distance between a point to any line. So, the lowest distance gives me the closest line to the point.

Since there are a huge number of points in this problem, it takes a huge calculations.
I am looking for an efficient and fast method for that.

Using the [Barycentric coordinate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system), I can find any point is surrounded with which lines. This trick will decrease the number of calculations. But, I am looking for more tricks to make it faster.

[image]

Comment: Have you considered a [quadtree](http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-use-quadtrees-to-detect-likely-collisions-in-2d-space--gamedev-374)? This could help you quickly determine a subset of lines to check.

Comment: Or [R-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree) (bounding box tree). Sometimes it is more effective than quadtree.

Comment: The closest line does not necessarily touch the closest point.
Voronoi diagram does not work.
Brute force for each line will give you O(n).

Comment: Actually, when you ask for the closest segment to each point the order is O(mxn) where m=#points and n =#segments. It can be unacceptable when these numbers are huge, and one of the best options is to use a PMRQuadTree. See: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/fcec/dd32bd3b181298f979fdef24a02a148e8bf4.pdf

Answer (score 0):

A voronoi diagram can gives you fast lookup. I think you can use the red points for the voronoi diagram. IMO the closest line is the same like the closest point.

Comment: I could imagine how you would use a Voronoi diagram here, but I'm not sure how this would speed up things. Furthermore, finding the Voronoi-cell which contains a given point requires some operations which are very similar to the one described by the question itself. - Could you provide some more details?

Comment: Probably the center point of a line segment would be appropriate for a Voronoi diagram (as long as there are no intersections). But then you'd still need an algorithm which efficiently makes use of the Voronoi diagram for finding the nearest neighbor (something like [this](http://infolab.usc.edu/papers/VorTree.pdf)), which essentially falls back to R-trees as suggested above...

Comment: Good point. IMO it's just to visualize things. I also think r-tree is good or more simple a hierarchical cluster or dendogram.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Voronoi diagram for ending points of segments.