# Find a point on line at minimal distance from N other point on the plane

Tags: c, algorithm, geometry, cartesian-coordinates

I have a line say line L, `lx + my + n = 0`. Now, Given some K points say, `(x1,y1),(x2, y2)...(xk,yk)` on xy plane on the line L or not , I want to find a point on the line L, say X`(x0,y0)` such that sum of distance between X and the 'N' points are minimal. What is the algorithm to solve such a question.
I thought about a solution where first I find the co-ordinates of point meeting the perpendicular to the line L from each point `(x1,y1),(x2, y2)...(xk,yk)`. Then I found out an average point of all those points where the perpendicular met the line L to find the least point. But such an approach is wrong. Please suggest the right method to solve the problem. Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
typedef struct
{
     int x;
     int y;
}point;

double distance(point * A, double x, double y)
{
    return sqrt(pow(A->x - x, 2) + pow(A->y - y, 2));
}


int main()
{
    int i = 0 , j = 0, test = 0, number_of_warehouse = 0, A = 0, B = 0, C = 0;
    point * point_array , *closest_points, sum;
    double avgx = 0.0, avgy  = 0.0, Total_dist = 0.0;
    scanf("%d", &test);

    while (test--)
    {
        scanf("%d", &number_of_warehouse);
        point_array = malloc (sizeof(point) * number_of_warehouse);
        closest_points = malloc (sizeof(point) * number_of_warehouse);
        scanf("%d%d%d", &A, &B,&C);
        sum.x = 0;
        sum.y = 0;
        avgx = 0;
        avgy = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < number_of_warehouse; ++i)
        {
            scanf("%d%d", &(point_array[i].x), &(point_array[i].y));
            closest_points[i].x = (B*(B * point_array[i].x - A * point_array[i].y) - A *C)/ (A*A + B*B);
            closest_points[i].y = (A*((-1)* B * point_array[i].x + A * point_array[i].y) - B *C)/ (A*A + B*B);
            sum.x +=  closest_points[i].x;
            sum.y +=  closest_points[i].y;
        }
        Total_dist = 0.0;
        avgx = sum.x / number_of_warehouse;
        avgy = sum.y / number_of_warehouse;
        for(i = 0; i < number_of_warehouse; ++i)
        {
            Total_dist += distance(point_array + i, avgx, avgy);
        }
        printf("%.6f", Total_dist);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can use a voronoi diagram look my answer here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24138386/the-best-way-for-finding-the-closest-line-segment-to-a-point/24140351#24140351.

Comment: Currently you try to minimize the sum of the distances, which in general is a very hard problem. If you instead minimize the sum of the *squared* distances there is a nice and simple solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the method of [least squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares), with the proper adjustments of course since your problem is a bit different. However, here is an outline of the process.

If we make `a = -l/m` and `b = -n/m`, we can write:

`y = ax + b`

this means the points in your straight line are of the form `(x ,ax + b)`, so the distance between any point in the straight line `(x ,y )` and the i-th point of your collection `(xi, yi)` is:

`di = sqrt [ (x - xi)^2 + (ax + b - yi)^2 ]`

Now we would have to minimize the summation form `0` to `k` of `di`, which is not a trivial problem. It is a usual approximation in regression analysis to minimize the squares of the distances, which has much simpler solution.

Expanding the squares and refactoring we have:

`di^2 = x^2  *k*(1 + a^2)  +  x (-2xi + 2kab - 2ayi) + (k*b^2 + yi^2 - 2byi + xi^2)`

Now, calculating the summation of `di^2` over all values of `i` and taking into account that summation is a linear operator, we can simply replace `xi` by the summation of all values of `xi`, and the same for `yi`, `xi^2` and `yi^2` (be careful with first calculating the square values and then summing them, although you will not need these values). For the terms that don't depend on `i`, they will be multiplied by `k`, since they will be summed `k` times.

Now we derivate and equate to zero the summation of `di^2`, to solve the equation for `x`

`d (di^2)/dx = 2k(1 + a^2) x + (-2*Sum(xi) + 2ab - 2a*Sum(yi)) = 0`

Finally, isolating `x` we obtain:

`x = (2*Sum(xi) - 2kab + 2a*Sum(yi))/2k(1+a^2)`

and `y` would be of course `ax + b`

Therefore you only need to calculate programmatically the summations of `xi` and `yi`, which should be very simple. Please check the algebra, which would also be a good exercise to understand the process.

Here is an example program implementing this algorithm and checking it with a simple case. If your collection of k points are in a line normal to the line where your point can move, then the closest point should be the intersection of both lines.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NUM_OF_POINTS 5

typedef struct
{
 double x;
 double y;
}point;


point findPoint (point *points, double slope, double intercept)
{
int i;
double sum_x = 0, sum_y = 0;
point your_point;


for( i = 0; i < NUM_OF_POINTS; ++i)
{
    sum_x += points[i].x;
    sum_y += points[i].y;
}

your_point.x = 2*(sum_x - NUM_OF_POINTS*slope*intercept + slope*sum_y)/(2*NUM_OF_POINTS*(1+slope*slope));

your_point.y = slope*your_point.x + intercept;

return your_point;


}

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
double slope = 1.0, intercept = 1.0;

    point point_arr [NUM_OF_POINTS], closest_point;

//Generate points in the line normal to y = slope*x + intercept

for (i = 0; i < NUM_OF_POINTS; i++)
{
    point_arr[i].x = 2.0 + i;
    point_arr[i].y = (-1.0/slope)*point_arr[i].x + 3.0;
}

closest_point = findPoint (point_arr, slope, intercept);
printf("Your point is %f, %f\n", closest_point.x, closest_point.y);


return 0;
}
```

The straight line is `y = x + 1` and the points are generated in the normal line `y = -x + 3`. The result is the point `(1,2)`, which is the intersection of both lines.

DP

Comment: Ditching the square roots is maybe an acceptable approximation - but it is definitely not an equivalence

Comment: It is not an approximation. If you have any real function `f(x)>=0` and `x0` such that `f(x0) = min{f(x)}` then the function `sqrt(f(x))` has also a minimum at `x0`. Consider the following: If `f(x)` has a minimum at `x0`, it means `f'(x0) = 0` and `f''(x0) < 0`. On the other hand, `sqrt(f(x))' = f(x)^(-1/2)*f'(x)`, which is zero except at `f(x0)=0` where `sqrt(x)` is not derivable, and `sqrt(f(x))''=f(x)^(-3/2)*f'(x)+f(x)^(-1/2)*f''(x)`. The first term is zero and the second term is < 0 at `x0`. Therefore `sqrt(f(x))` has a min at `x0`. When `f(x0)=0` then `sqrt(f(x0))=0`, so both have a min.

Comment: what you say is true for a single square root, but the function to minimize is a sum of square roots. `sqrt(f1(x)) + sqrt(f2(x))` and `f1(x) + f2(x)` do not share the position of the minimum (in general).

Comment: `@coproc` What an oversight! You are absolutely right! That should teach me to trust my memory less and pay more attention. Thanks for the observation. I will edit my post accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You can represent the solution mathematically as :-

```
lx + my + n = 0

and 

Say you want to minimize squared distances then :-

S = sum((xk-x)^2 + (yk-y)^2) for all N points.

y = (n-mx)/l from line equation

S = sum((xk-x)^2 + (yk-(n-mx)/l)^2)

S = sum((xk-x)^2 + (ykl-n+mx)^2/l^2))

Diff wrt to x for minimizing 

S = sum(2*(xk-x) + 2m*(ykl-n+mx)/l^2) = 0

Distributing summation

S = sum(xk) - sum(x) + (m/l^2)*( l*sum(yk) - sum(n) + m*sum(x))) = 0

S = sum(xk) - N*x + (m/l^2)*(l*sum(yk) - N*n + m*N*x) = 0

(1-m^2/l^2)*N*x = sum(xk) + (m/l^2)*(l*sum(yk)-N*n)

Find x using the equation and then find y using line equation
```

Answer (score 1):

The locus of points P such that the sums of distances of P from given fixed n points (not all collinear) is constant (say D) is a convex set, called a n-ellipse and the corresponding n-ellipse for distance D' lies completely within the n-ellipse for D, for D' < D. (A 2-ellipse is an actual ellipse)

Thus there is a unique (global) minimum among points on the given line, and a hill climbing algorithm will work.

See this paper: [n-ellipses and the minimum distance problem](http://www.jstor.org/pss/2589675) for a proof of the above claims.

@DissidentPenguin: Minimizing x_1 + x_2 is different from minimizing sqrt(x_1) + sqrt(x_2) (which you are confusing with sqrt(x_1 + x_2)).

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there is a closed-form solution.

This means that you will have to use a numeric approximation.

### Generic

I.e., you need to implement the function `double tot_dist(double x)` where `x` is the coordinate on your line and `tot_dist` computes the sum of distances.

Then you need to pass it to one of the gazillion min-finding functions available (e.g., for [Mathematica](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NumericalOptimization.html), R: [optim](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/optim.html), [optimize](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/optimize.html)).

### Problem specific

If you move your point `x` along the line by a tiny distance `h`, the distance from `x` to `X_k` will change by `h*cos(a)` where `a` is the angle between the line `L` and the the line `xX_k`. This means that your solution satisfies the nice equation `sum(cos(a_k))=0`, i.e., instead of using a generic minimizer, you can use the [Newton's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) to find the zero of the `double sum_cos_angle(double x)` function (you will need to compute the derivative of `sum_cos_angle`, but this should not be a big deal).

### Voronoi

The suggested [Voronoi diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram) solution is *not* applicable here because this is a *global* problem (distances to *all* points), and Voronoi is for *local* problems (the closest *one* point). Basically, if we wiggle a single point `X_k`, the solution to this problem will change. On the other hand, Voronoi diagram depends only on the location of the closest 2 points, so, if we wiggle a single *distant* point, the diagram will not change and, thus, any solution obtained with it will not change either.

Comment: @Phpdna: no, I don't think so. This is a _global_ problem (distances to _all_ points), and voronoi is for _local_ problems (the closest _one_ point).  Are you the downvoter?

Comment: Can you elaborate global and local?

Comment: @Phpdna: please see PS

Comment: Maybe you can use a hierarchical cluster and a voronoi diagram. Then the top hierarchy subdivide the points into at most 3 cluster.